# Conditional field using dynamic vocabularies to custom fields on @@register

Tags: plone, zope

I'm following [collective.examples.userdata](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.examples.userdata) to add some custom fields on the register form.

I want to add two fields, one for state and another for city, where the second load content based on the previously selected state.

My question is how it is possible, can do this only with the schema, using [dynamic vocabularies](http://developer.plone.org/forms/vocabularies.html#dynamic-vocabularies) or is need to edit registration form? How can I do it?

Another issue is how to load the registration form in a portlet. Is Possible fill the @@register viewlet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to do the dynamic part of the secondary field. To render the form inside a portlet, there are a couple of ways to do it but again, using javascript might be the easiest.  You have place a register button that opens a registration overlay.

Take a look at http://plone.org/products/plone.app.jquerytools for how to wire it up.